# How to make my notification stays on top?

Tags: java, android, notifications, channel

I have a media-style notification that shows when a media-service starts foreground. I would like this notification to stay always on top of all others notifications 
I've set both channel and notification priorities to HIGH and MAX, but the notification doesn't even show on top, it appears below some older notifications...

Here is my createChannel method :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Notification channel name";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setSound(null, null);
            channel.setDescription("Notification channel description");
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            // Enregister le canal sur le système : attention de ne plus rien modifier après
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

And the notification :

```
  Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)

                .setContentTitle(chanson)
                .setContentText(artiste)
                .setLargeIcon(icone)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "pause", pausePendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
```

Comment: Try to set your notification category to [`CATEGORY_TRANSPORT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)

Comment: I tried and played with different categories, but it didn't change anything :(